# Need tips for creating responsive content hover element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

Now i need your help for creating this “content hover element” for customers
Concrete5 site..

Here’s my site so far: testi4.aada.fi

There is this one hover element that i’m working on right now which should work like this: http://testi4.aada.fi/files/7514/1802/2403/kwh_hover.png

and i have no idea how to manage to code that..

There is this image and when user places mouse over it user should get other div under that image with content..

Any tips are more than welcome!!!

// Mika

Comment: Wlcome Mika, can you please show us your code, what you have fro now?

Comment: You have 8 questions and 0 accepted answers. You might want to work on that to get some quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

Simple hover effect, if need some extra animations, use jQuery.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
.hover {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.wrapper:hover .hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals" />
  <div class="hover">
    some text here;
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" />
  <div class="hover">
    some text here;
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city" />
  <div class="hover">
    some text here;
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for this !!!!!  You can see it action here with little modification .. testi4.aada.fi